# Input dimensionality using pre-trained CNNs in Keras for transfer learning

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I want to experiment with using some of the pre-trained CNN models available with the Keras library (e.g. Exception, ResNet50, etc) for feature extraction. I am trying to find out whether the input dimensionality of my dataset needs to match the dimensionality of the images used for training the original CNN.

For example; should I be using a network model pre-trained on 210x210 RGB images, does this mean the network will only work with images of the same dimensionality (i.e. (210, 210, 3)) if I want to use it for feature extraction? Or is there some flexibility in this regard?

Tried searching Google and checking the Keras documentation, but could not find an explicit answer regarding this question! Any input from someone with experience in this matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean Inception, not Exception. Or maybe Xception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is possible, you can change the `input_shape` of a pretrained model. It is even mentioned on the keras.aplications [documentation](https://keras.io/applications/).

Build InceptionV3 over a custom input tensor

```
from keras.applications.inception_v3 import InceptionV3
from keras.layers import Input

# this could also be the output a different Keras model or layer
# this assumes K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last'
input_tensor = Input(shape=(224, 224, 3))  

model = InceptionV3(input_tensor=input_tensor, weights='imagenet',
                    include_top=False)
```

Note that if you want to use a model with images of different size than the training ones, you must set `include_top` to `False`, as the fully connected layers for the model are constrained only to accept features with the right dimensionality, the one produced by the original training image sizes.

Comment: Interesting answer -- I see that `include_top = False` makes those models fully convolutional (removes the dense layers at the end).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no flexibility. (But take a look at Matias Valdenegro's answer)

Keras models work with a static defined dimension.

Changing the dimensions imply in changing all the resulting dimensions of the following convolutional layers, and also changing the amount of weights of all dense layers, for instance. (So, what to do with the new or missing weights? They will affect the calculations)

If a model is purely convolutional, perhaps you can manually mimic its structure in a different size, copy its weights, figure out the new output shape and try to use it (this can be achieved by `include_top=False` as in Matias Valdenegro's answer). But if it's a classification model, you'll have a problem, because either they use dense layers at the end, or their final convolutional layers need to end in a fixed size for classification.

But even in the purely convolutional case, if the model is not trained to all kinds of different sizes and positions of objects in the image, it can lose its ability to recognize things, because its convolutional filters are searching for features in a fixed size in pixels.

---

Things you can do to work around this problem are:

- padding the inputs to meet the necessary size: the model must be well trained not to go crazy about huge dark areas in the image thinking they mean something.
- dividing the inputs in smaller areas of the picture, maybe with a little overlap (to avoid cutting objects in two and making then unrecognizable by the model). Then you join the respective outputs properly.